# PHP Header not redirecting to home.php

Tags: php

I'm trying to make the header redirect, it was working like 2 days ago and I don't know what i've done to break it. It now just reloads the page but starts the session.

This is the code,

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['id']))

{
 header("Location: home.php");
}

require_once 'global.php';

?>

<head>
 <title>BookWizard - Join Now!</title>




<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="FORMETER jQuery plugin" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marmelad">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_secure/stylesheets/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/formeter.1.0.css" />
    <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
                  </script><![endif]-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">

    </script>
    <script src="javascript/formeter.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#percentage').formProgress({
                'speed' : 800,
                'style' : 'green',
                'bubble' : true,
                'selector' : '.recommended'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a class="logo" href="index.html"><!-- --></a>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">




        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="container">

            <div id="registercontainerno">

         <img src="images/logo.png" class="frontpagelogo">


   <div class="meter" style="position:absolute; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 20px;">
                    <div id="percentage" data-percent=""></div>
                </div>



      <br><br><br><br>

            <h2 class="paragraphf">BookWizard Information</h2>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['password']))
{
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);

$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'")) == 0) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (firstname, email, avatar, password, username, lastname)
  VALUES ('$firstname', '$email', 'http://book-wizard.net/images/default.png',   
 '$password',   '$username', '$lastname')");
$_SESSION['id'] = $username;
Header('Location: home.php');
}
else {
echo "Error, Please try again later.";
die();
}
}
?>

            <form method="post">
<img src="/images/regi.jpg" align="right" style="margin-top: -100px; margin-right:
10px; border-radius: 5px;">
                <p class="paragraphf">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="recommended" />
                </p>
                <p class="paragraphf">
                <label>Password</label> 

 <input type="password" name="password" class="recommended" />      

                <h2 class="paragraphf">Personal Information</h2>
                <p class="paragraphf">
                    <label>First name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="recommended" />
                </p>
                <p class="paragraphf">
                    <label>Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" class="recommended" />
                </p>

                <h2 class="paragraphf">Contact Information</h2>
                <p class="paragraphf">
                <label>Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="recommended" />






                <p class="input_bg">
    <input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" class="buttonr blue"><a href="index.php"  

 class="buttonr orange">CANCEL</a>
                    <br><br>
                </p>
            </form>

            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div> <!-- END container -->
    </div> <!-- END wrapper -->

    </body>
</html>
```

and in the global.php it does have a session_start();... not sure the problem :S

Comment: just print the print_r($_SESSION) at  below <?php the line.check whether $_SESSION['id'] is available or not.

Answer (score 1):

Are you including session_start() at the top of your page, BEFORE this piece of code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
 header("Location: home.php");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've just done that and I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: put print_r($_SESSION); at the top of your page and see what you have;

Answer (score 0):

`require_once 'global.php';` should be in top, since there is `session_start()`.

```
require_once 'global.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
 header("Location: home.php");
}
```

Comment: I've moved it to the top, but getting the same problem. The session starts, but it doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Include `global.php` before anything else, if that's where you keep your `session_start`.

Answer (score 0):

**Move `require_once 'global.php';` to the top of your page.**

You need to call `session_start()` before you can use session variables!

```
<?php
  require_once 'global.php';

  if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
  {
    header("Location: home.php");
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to redirect all users that don't already have a session (visit for the first time) to `home.php`, but that is not the way to go. You cannot check the `$_SESSION` variable before it was filled by calling `session_start()`, and after calling session_start(), you will always have a session id in the variable.

What you can do, is to establish a session at the begin of your script, then check, if a certain variable is already set.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['already_been_here']))
{
  $_SESSION['already_been_here'] = true;
  header('Location: home.php', true, 303);
  exit;
}
```

Don't forget to call exit after the redirect, the script will continue to execute otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change these lines:

```
{
 header("Location: home.php");
}
```

with these:

```
{
 header("Location: home.php");
 exit();
}
```

?